# Redirecting a query search from old domain to the new domain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect a query search from my old domain to my new domain

like mysite.com/?q=foo to othersite.com/?s=foo

using .htaccess

I've tried any .htaccess codes but not worked well.

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault. It will really help if you mention the methods you have already tried unsuccessfully. You might also want to take a look at [this guide to creating a constructive question](http://serverfault.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RedirectMatch` comes in handy for building URI based redirects. You'll find lots of complicated examples involving `mod_rewrite` on the internet, but it's important to remember that `mod_rewrite` is [the solution for when nothing else works](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RedirectMatch ^/\?q=(.*) http://othersite.com/?s=$1
</IfModule>
```

This redirect should apply to any request beginning with a URI of `/?q=`, capture everything after the `=`, and insert the captured search string into the redirect.

Comment: Please note that I've edited this answer. The original did not apply an escape to the question mark.

Comment: what sould I do then to make this code work?

Comment: I'm assuming that you figured out what I meant since you accepted the answer. Let me know in additional detail if that is not the case. I hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysite.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://othersite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks, but how to redirect such different query like
mysite.com/?q=foo to othersite.com/?s=foo

see that ?q is changed to ?s

I have try your sample but mysite.com/?q=foo will just othersite.com/?q=foo